# params[:person_id] returns NilClass although a value is permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to access params[:person_id] which seems to be permitted because I notice that from the webtrick log but this expression returns NilClass. Why?

```
class ClubsController < ApplicationController
    private
        def set_stored_with_own_address
            logger.debug("params[:person_id]: #{params[:person_id].class}") # => NilClass
            logger.debug("params: #{params.class}") # => ActionController::Parameters
            @stored_with_own_address = params[:person_id].nil?
            logger.debug("Was stored with own address: #{@stored_with_own_address}") # => true
        end
end
```

My params hash is:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"2HnqCni+Yy2jMY0vKhUNcAreD1vdAISrLkURuTso7AM=", "club"=>{"caption"=>"xxx", "region_id"=>"1", "bdk_number"=>"4711", "website"=>"xxx", "person_id"=>"1", "address_attributes"=>{"street"=>"", "street_visibility"=>"0", "zip"=>"", "city"=>"", "zip_city_visibility"=>"0", "phone"=>"", "phone_visibility"=>"0", "mobil"=>"", "mobil_visibility"=>"0", "fax"=>"", "fax_visibility"=>"0", "mail"=>"", "mail_visibility"=>"0", "id"=>"15"}}, "commit"=>"Verein speichern", "id"=>"17"}
```

Comment: Show your whole `params` hash.

Comment: Where is def set_stored_with_own_address?  Can it see params?

Comment: There is no Ajax request. This is a regular request to the create method.

Answer (score 1):

You should access it using `params[:club][:person_id]`. Notice that `person_id` is inside the `club` param object.